# Gnome shell privilege escalation

Tags: linux, gnome-3, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

I'm building a Gnome shell extension, and I want to be able to do some things with escalated privileges.  So, I'm thinking I need to use "policy kit", but I don't know how to do go about doing this.

So, say I wanted to do something like `ifconfig eth0 down` or `ifconfig eth0 up`

I can run from the terminal: `pkexec ifconfig eth0 down` and it will prompt for a password and then do it.

But, how am I supposed to do it from inside an extension?

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with making a file in /usr/share/polkit-1/actions, but I can't find anything on the internet or otherwise.

I want to be able to set it up so that there is no need for a password to be typed in, and the extension can just run the certain command whenever.

I know that it is a really bad idea to allow *any* command to be run.  That is not what I am asking for, I want to be able to just run a single program/command.

EDIT: I'm not sure, but I think it might be impossible for there to be no need to type in a password. I just know that sudo doesn't ask for the password for a while after the first time, so I kind of want similar functionality. Not sure what possible.

Comment: This is generally a not going to work too well, because your shell extension (in JavaScript) is going to be running inside the same process as the shell itself, thus exposing it to all kinds of security “leaks…” — The safe bet would, in fact, be to use `pkexec` or otherwise isolate the “unsafe” bit of privileged code in a separate process… PS: The re-prompting for a password by `sudo` et al is a system-wide security setting; the default is usually to re-prompt after a (long) while

Comment: @BRPocock yes using `pkexec` is what I want to do.  How would I do that from within the extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a long time since I didn't work with PolicyKit, but from what I remember, you have indeed to create a file in the actions/ directory, with contents like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policyconfig PUBLIC
 "-//freedesktop//DTD PolicyKit Policy Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/PolicyKit/1/policyconfig.dtd">
<policyconfig>

  <action id="org.freedesktop.policykit.pkexec.run-ifconfig">
    <description>Configure network</description>
    <message>Authentication is required to set ifconfig parameters</message>
    <defaults>
      <allow_any>no</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>...</allow_active>
    </defaults>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/sbin/ifconfig</annotate>
  </action>

</policyconfig>
```

You have to change the value in :

```
<allow_active>...</allow_active>
```

To the value you want. Selecting a value of :

- "no" will deny access
- "yes" will implicitly permits access
- "auth_user" requires user authentication
- "auth_admin" requires admin authentication.
- "auth_user_keep" and "auth_admin_keep" function similarly but retain authentication for a few minutes afterward.
- Plus some other values, view [here](http://beginlinux.com/appsm/policykit/922-declaringactions).

Changing the allow_active key's value to "yes" should stop the authentication demands.

Then you need to adapt the action file to your needs and to call it.

Hugo,

Answer (score 1):

I was having much the same issue to try and implement a selector for tuned. Here is what I came up with.

As others answered, you may need to write a policy file (I used "auth_admin"). I placed it in 
"/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/tuned-adm.policy." I don't think I can distrib that through the extensions model, so I will have to ask upstream to include it.

Next, I used pkexec and my command to get the "sudo popup" and got it to work.

```
const GLib = imports.gi.GLib;
const Util = imports.misc.util;
this.pkexec_path = GLib.find_program_in_path('pkexec');
this.tunedadm_path = GLib.find_program_in_path('tuned-adm');
let result = Util.trySpawnCommandLine(this.pkexec_path + " " + this.tunedadm_path  + " list")
```

The real kicker here was I used a couple of other methods to run the command line and they would lock up gnome-shell. I found the code here: https://github.com/nodefourtytwo/gnome-shell-extension-cpu-freq/blob/master/extension.js to be particularly handy.